# Result if TOP 10 values are not there

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT AVG(f.P_PRICE_LOW) as TOP10_Average
FROM (SELECT top 10 P_PRICE_LOW
      FROM fp_basic_bd
      WHERE fs_perm_sec_id='B00242-S-US'
      ORDER BY fs_perm_sec_id
     ) as f
```

By using this query I am calculating the average of top 10 price values. My question is:

How the average will be calculated if the subquery returns less than 10 values?

Comment: If your query works, you are most likely using SQL Server.  I changed the tag.

Comment: Avg = `sum(P_PRICE_LOW) / number of not null P_PRICE_LOW records` . If you have less then 10 `P_PRICE_LOW` then, example 8 not null `P_PRICE_LOW` records then Avg =  `sum(P_PRICE_LOW)/8`

Comment: You are not "calculating the average of top 10 price values", you are calculating the average of 10 arbitrary prices.

Comment: Yes - `ORDER BY fs_perm_sec_id` - it's probably a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The average is calculated over whatever the inner query returns, with NULL values  being ignored by `AVG()`.

- If inner query returns 10 non-null values, then result = SUM(10 values) / 10.
- If inner query returns 3 non-null values, then result = SUM(3 values) / 3.
- If inner query returns no non-null values or even no values at all, then result = NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `TOP` as restricting the total number of rows returned, not adding or manipulating any values. So if your query returns 90 rows total, `TOP` will just return the first N of those, so the first 10 in your case. If there are less than N rows returned, then `TOP` will return all rows found since it did not exceed the maximum value specified.

For your specific case, if your subquery returned <10 rows, the average value found would be based on those rows instead of 10. Since you are using the `AVG` function instead of manually finding the average yourself, the value found will still be the correct average of the rows found. So if you have 6 rows returned in the subquery, `AVG` would do the same as `(r1 + r2 + ... + r6)/6`.